# Check if VC 2017 redist has been installed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, registry, detect

Checking previous versions was trivial 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2010/05/05/mailbag-how-to-detect-the-presence-of-the-visual-c-2010-redistributable-package/

if you need 2010 you should use 10.0 for the next release 11.0... 14.0

Everything works as it was expected until VS 2017 where the entry 15.0 exists but there is no VC folder inside it and of course there is no such key as "installed"

Anyone had to deal with this?

Thank you in advance